# can't zoom in and zoom out of a HIChart's Line/Bar chart in Xcode Simulator using Swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

I am trying to set zoom in and zoom out functionality to my HIChart. I am using below code -

```
          let chart = HIChart()
          chart.type = "column"
//        chart.zoomType = "x"
//        chart.zoomType = "y"
//        chart.zoomType = "xy"
          chart.pinchType = "x"
          chart.panning = NSNumber(value: true  )
          options.chart = chart
```

I have tried either with setting `zoomType` and `pinchType` but both are not working on iOS Xcode simulator. Please let me know the solution if anyone has tried.

There is no issue with scrolling as it is working with this code -

```
   chart.scrollablePlotArea = HIScrollablePlotArea()
   chart.scrollablePlotArea.minWidth = 700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `chart.zoomType` to one of the accepted values: `["x", "y", "xy"]`. Then you can zoom in the simulator by holding 'alt' key.

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was unaware of holding 'alt' key. Please let me know When to use -
          chart.pinchType = "x"
          chart.panning = NSNumber(value: true  )

Comment: Hi @Tejas Ratunawar, I am glad that I could help. From API: `pinchType - 
Equivalent to zoomType, but for multitouch gestures only. By default, the pinchType is the same as the zoomType setting. However, pinching can be enabled separately in some cases, for example in stock charts where a mouse drag pans the chart, while pinching is enabled. When tooltip.followTouchMove is true, pinchType only applies to two-finger touches.`